# Do not store failed commands in fish history

Tags: fish

I was wondering if it is possible to avoid storing commands in fish history which have failed. At the moment I e.g. have commands like `:q` stored in my fish history, because I accidentally typed that in the shell instead of vim.

The command makes no sense and the command line, and therefore fails, which makes totally sense. But it would be nice if there would be a possibility to avoid having this failed command in my fish history, because it clutters autocompletion with a lot of senseless commands. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Define "failed command" first.

Comment: I think with a command not existing at all I already gave a good example. Would already be glad if this would not be added to the history. And in a more naiive approach I would say any exit code not being 0, but I've already been told that this is not a very reliable way of solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like it is currently possible, there is an open issue for that: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5